Why magnetic field inside hollow iron box is zero?
During my practice for magnetic materials test I encountered a question, which asked about the intensity of magnetic field of the earth at a point inside a hollow iron box.  The answer is zero.
But my question is the point inside the hollow iron box is not present on any magnetic material.  So the B external should remain same.  But why do here it is zero?

Since the box is closed, the magnetic field is all in the iron

is it because of gauss law of magnetism or something else

It is Gauss law. but you need an iron box not just a closed surface.
